# Safari Horizontal scroll issue with footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

i have issue with footer, it is displaying after main div if we scroll y.

Please check with this url [Click Here](http://139.59.31.241/).

i notice if there is any issue with animation or keyframe. and i check many questions but that not solve my issue.

footer css is:

```
footer.bg-light.o_footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the overflow-x to hidden.

```
#wrapwrap {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: it not solve the issue. after this change it effect to animation of divs

Comment: Looks fixed to me. What animation did it affect?

Comment: the animation when you scroll down, from left/right animation's div is stop working with this change.

Comment: but it works when i do change in selector, 
#wrapwrap {overflow-x: hidden !important;}
Thanks for that :)